# Calling "other" ImageMagick commands through Imagick?

Tags: php, shell, graphics, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using the [Imagick](http://us.php.net/imagick) PHP wrapper for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.html). I've noticed there are some ImageMagick commands that are not available in the Imagick wrapper, such as [`autolevel`](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#auto-level) and [`normalize`](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#normalize).

How should I go about calling these? Couldn't find anything in Imagick. Are there disadvantages to calling the ImageMagick commands directly through the shell with `exec()` or `shell_exec()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using `system()`. For some reason, `exec()` doesn't work on my MacBook.

Comment: Was hoping there'd be a way to do it without escaping to shell, but... guess not.